# Поиск и переименование файлов и папок

Tags: python

Не судите строго, это мой первый код на Python. Ситуация следующая: Программа должна искать указанную подстроку `FindFileName` в именах файлов и папок, в найденных объектах указанная часть `FindFileStr` имени заменяется на указанную подстроку `ReplaceFileStr`.

Проблема: Программа переименовывает объекты только в корне дисков, то есть не затрагивает объекты находящиеся в других папках.

```
import os, time

FindFileName = input("Введите имя файла для поиска:")
FindFileStr = input("Какую часть в имени '" + FindFileName + "' будем заменять?:")
ReplaceFileStr = input("На что будем заменять часть '" + FindFileStr + "' в имени '" + FindFileName + "' ?:")

StartTime = time.time()
Disk = ["q:/","w:/","e:/","r:/","t:/","y:/","u:/","i:/","o:/","p:/","a:/","s:/","d:/","f:/","h:/","j:/","k:/","l:/","z:/","x:/","c:/","v:/","b:/","n:/","m:/"]

for fDisk in Disk:
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(fDisk):
        #print("Поиск в '" + rootdir + "'")
        for file in files:
            finds = file.lower()
            if(finds.find(FindFileName.lower()) != -1):
                os.rename(os.path.join(rootdir,file), os.path.join(rootdir,file.replace(FindFileStr, ReplaceFileStr)))
                print("* -", os.path.join(rootdir,file),"- переименован в -", os.path.join(rootdir,file.replace(FindFileStr, ReplaceFileStr)),"-")
        for dird in dirs:
            finds = dird.lower()
            if(finds.find(FindFileName.lower()) != -1):
                os.rename(os.path.join(rootdir,dird), os.path.join(rootdir,dird.replace(FindFileStr, ReplaceFileStr)))
                print("* -", os.path.join(rootdir,dird),"- переименован в -", os.path.join(rootdir,dird.replace(FindFileStr, ReplaceFileStr)),"-")


print("Скрипт выполнен за %d секунд." % (time.time() - StartTime))
```

Comment: Посмотрите примеры вызова и использования `os.walk()`.

Comment: Именно примерами и руководствовался. При помощи функции print я убедился что цикл проходит через все файлы и папки, включая подкаталоги, но почему-то всё-равно переименовывает только в корне диска...

Comment: Прочитайте документацию внимательно https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os

Comment: Спасибо, Вам за совет. Оказалось, что если программа переименовывает папку, то в ней поиск далее не производится. Решением проблемы стало изменение параметра topdown=False, который позволил функции перебрать объекты в обратном порядке. То есть мы сначала обрабатываем имена объектов в папке, за тем имя самой папки.